# PHP multidimensional array (usort)

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, associative, usort

I have an associative array like this

```
Array
(
    ["News 1"] => Array
        (
            [text] => tests
            [language] => 
            [advertiserCompetitionScale] => 5
            [avgSearchVolume] => 7480000
            [lastMonthSearchVolume] => 9140000
        )

    ["News 2"] => Array
        (
            [text] => personality tests
            [language] => 
            [advertiserCompetitionScale] => 5
            [avgSearchVolume] => 165000
            [lastMonthSearchVolume] => 201000
        )

    ["News 3] => Array
        (
            [text] => online tests
            [language] => 
            [advertiserCompetitionScale] => 5
            [avgSearchVolume] => 246000
            [lastMonthSearchVolume] => 301000
        )

)
```

I managed to sort it by the column i want (LastMonthSearchVolume for example)

```
// compare function 
function cmpi($a, $b) 
{ 

     return strcmp($a["lastMonthSearchVolume"], $b["lastMonthSearchVolume"]); 
} 

// do the array sorting 
usort($latest_array, 'cmpi');
```

The problem is when i dump the array to see the result the usort broke my associative array by removing "News 1", "News 2" etc.. and replacing it by 0,1,2...

Is there any solution to make sort keep the column  name ?

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

In place of [`usort`](http://php.net/usort), use the function [`uasort`](http://php.net/uasort), which preserves index association.

Answer (score 1):

Use [uasort](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.uasort.php) instead. `usort` does not maintain associative keys, while `uasort` does.