# How to understand usort logic?

Tags: php, sorting, usort

I'm trying to understand how php function [usort](http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php) works.
I have such code:

```
<?php 
$users[] = array('login' => 'moon', 'name' => 'Chris');
$users[] = array('login' => 'star', 'name' => 'Piter');
$users[] = array('login' => 'mars', 'name' => 'Tim');
$users[] = array('login' => 'earth', 'name' => 'Garry');

function compare($a, $b) {                  
    echo $a['login'] . '--' . $b['login'] . '<br />';
    echo strcmp($a['login'], $b['login']) . '<br />';
    return strcmp($a['login'], $b['login']);              
}
usort($users, "compare");

echo '<pre>'; print_r($users); echo '</pre>';
?>
```

It will output such result:

```
star--moon
1
star--mars
1
earth--star
-1
moon--earth
1
mars--moon
-1
earth--mars
-1
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [login] => earth
            [name] => Garry
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [login] => mars
            [name] => Tim
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [login] => moon
            [name] => Chris
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [login] => star
            [name] => Piter
        )

)
```

As far as I understand second param should be comparison function and it can only return 3 values (-1,0,1) and `usort` use this results to sort array? Also I read, `usort` use Quicksort implementation to sort array. That is why **star** is first and **moon** - second? Quicksort divide array into two parts and then sort it? And can I implement this function for 2,3 dimensions array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, usort uses the comparison function, to compare the values and sort the array with the [quicksort](http://sv.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort) algorithm. From http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php:

> The comparison function must return an integer less than, equal to, or greater than zero if the first argument is considered to be respectively less than, equal to, or greater than the second.

Links to the implementation of usort in PHP can be found here: [What sort algorithm does PHP use?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3165984/what-sort-algorithm-does-php-use). According to http://murilo.wordpress.com/2011/02/05/phps-sort-functions-are-bad-designed/ the algorithm uses the middle element as the pivot element, implemented as this:

```
offset = (end - begin) >> 1;
```

This should be why the algorithm uses 'star' as the first pivot element.

For multidimensional arrays, use [uasort](https://www.php.net/uasort) if you want to maintain index association. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9483215/php-multidimensional-array-usort) contains an example of sorting multidimensional arrays.

Comment: Great answer. But can you explain one moment. In the article at your answer written that better to use `shuffle` before sorting. This `shuffle` has no influence on pivot element? It's algorithm feature that it better work with shuffled arrays?

Comment: Yes, shuffling the array before sorting may avoid worst-case scenarios, like when the array is already sorted, but the algorithm still picks the middle element as the pivot element. But this middle element is probably a different element after shuffling the array, than before shuffling.

Answer (score 1):

You're telling `usort` which item to place first when it compares any two items in your array. Your function is returning the `strcmp` comparison of the `login` values of the elements, so it's putting all of your elements in alphabetical order based on the login name.

Comment: And how it decide what elements it should compare during next iteration? And, also, it should compare every element each other?

Comment: Read the comments on http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php - specifically the first one. It doesn't compare every element with every other element - the sorting algorithm doesn't need to.